# WEMOS D1 + DallasTemperature: How to print temperature and temperature comparison in if

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266, temperature

I make a controller of heating with DS18B20 and Wemos D1 board, but if i try print or check the temperature in `if` then give back 0 in `int`.
What is the problem?

```
//  This Arduino sketch reads DS18B20 "1-Wire" digital
//  temperature sensors.
//  Copyright (c) 2010 Mark McComb, hacktronics LLC
//  License: <a href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php" rel="nofollow">http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</a> (Go crazy)
//  Tutorial:
//  <a href="http://www.hacktronics.com/Tutorials/arduino-1-wire-tutorial.html" rel="nofollow">http://www.hacktronics.com/Tutorials/arduino-1-wire-tutorial.html</a>

#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into pin 3 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 0

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// Assign the addresses of your 1-Wire temp sensors.
// See the tutorial on how to obtain these addresses:
// <a href="http://www.hacktronics.com/Tutorials/arduino-1-wire-address-finder.html" rel="nofollow">http://www.hacktronics.com/Tutorials/arduino-1-wire-address-finder.html</a>
const int mintemp = 30;
DeviceAddress insideThermometer = { 0x28,  0xFF,  0x83,  0x51,  0xB2,  0x17,  0x4,  0x8A };
DeviceAddress outsideThermometer = { 0x28,  0xFF,  0x4F,  0xAB,  0xC4,  0x17,  0x5,  0x83 };
DeviceAddress dogHouseThermometer = { 0x28,  0xFF,  0xBF,  0xA9,  0xC4,  0x17,  0x4,  0x7C };

void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(112500);
  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();
  // set the resolution to 10 bit (good enough?)
  sensors.setResolution(insideThermometer, 10);
  sensors.setResolution(outsideThermometer, 10);
  sensors.setResolution(dogHouseThermometer, 10);
}

void printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  if (tempC == -127.00) {
    Serial.print("Error getting temperature");
  } else {
    Serial.print("C: ");
    Serial.print(tempC);
    Serial.print(" F: ");
    Serial.print(DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC));
  }
}

void loop(void)
{
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Getting temperatures...\n\r");
  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  Serial.print("Inside temperature is: ");
  printTemperature(insideThermometer);
  Serial.print("\n\r");
  Serial.print("Outside temperature is: ");
  printTemperature(outsideThermometer);
  Serial.print("\n\r");
  Serial.print("Dog House temperature is: ");
  printTemperature(dogHouseThermometer);
  Serial.print("\n\r\n\r");
  int insideThermometer = (int)insideThermometer;
    Serial.print(insideThermometer); //In Serial this give 0.
  if(insideThermometer > mintemp){
    Serial.print("work");
    Serial.print(insideThermometer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I looked at the listing, but it is not clear to what if or print you are refering. I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: `int insideThermometer = (int)insideThermometer;` Use a different name.

Comment: Also, the global `insideThermometer` is an array.  What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: Ohh, I did not know it was an array. I want to print the temperature from the array. How could this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
int insideThermometer = (int)insideThermometer;
```

You create a local variable and assign it to itself. Not what you wanted. The global var you are trying to use is

```
DeviceAddress insideThermometer = { 0x28,  0xFF,  0x83,  0x51,  0xB2,  0x17,  0x4,  0x8A };
```

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library), `DeviceAddress` is typdef'd as

```
typedef uint8_t DeviceAddress[8];
```

If you want to get the temperature you need to call `sensors.getTempC(insideThermometer)`, which you already do in the `printTemperature` function. Since you call that function before testing the temp, just modify it to return the temp:

```
float printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  float tempF = 0;
  if (tempC == -127.00) {
    Serial.print("Error getting temperature");
  } else {
    Serial.print("C: ");
    Serial.print(tempC);
    Serial.print(" F: ");
    tempF = DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC);
    Serial.print(tempF);
  }
  return tempF;
}
```

Then change to

```
int insideTempF = printTemperature(insideThermometer);
....
if (insideTempF > mintemp) {
    ....
```

(You may want to change the name of the function to something like `printAndReturnTemperature` as that more clearly states its new functionality.)